# Simplify Derivative with Substitution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I try to evaluate:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log{u(x, y, z)}$$

Mathematica gives:

$$ \frac{1}{x+y+z}$$

I want to simplify the expression with my function:

$$ \frac{1}{u(x, y, z)}$$

How to do that?

Thanks.

```
u[x_, y_, z_] = x + y + z
Simplify[D[Log[u[x, y, z]], x]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
D[Log[u[x, y, z]], x] /. u[x_, y_, z_] :> Defer[u[x, y, z]]
```

> 1/u[x, y, z]

Comment: A more general substitution:  `/. u[x_,y_,z_] -> Defer[u[x,y,z]]`

Comment: @Rzu, good point.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to define [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) instead of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) of `u`:

```
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u] ^:= 1&
Derivative[0, 1, 0][u] ^:= 1&
Derivative[0, 0, 1][u] ^:= 1&

D[Log[u[x, y, z]], x]
```

> 1/u[x, y, z]

Comment: What are UpValues and DownValues? The definition in the doc seems recursive: `UpValue` "gives a list of transformation rules corresponding to all *upvalues* defined for the symbol f. "

Comment: @Rzu Maybe you can check out the documentation for [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed) and [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed).